# How to create a Event CountDown Timer?

Tags: php, jquery, countdown

Hi How to create a CountDown Timer?
Is there any good tutorial about it?
PHP and JQuery based. thanks.

Comment: You can see [this plugin](http://blog.deepscripts.com/how-to-build-an-awsome-responsive-animated-countdown-using-jquery-raphael-library/). It's very well designed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).